# App quits unexpectedly when I entered this code (using core data)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

App quits unexpectedly when I enter this code (using core data). I am using `CoreData` object in this screen for adding and removing data. I don't know why this code crashes the app everytime when I enter this screen.
This problem occurs:  when I add Category in Core Data Object and when I fetch Core Data Object.

CoreData.swift

```
class categoryCoreData {

    static func saveData(tfCat: String)
    {
        let cat = Category(context: context)
        cat.category_name = tfCat

        // Save the data to coredata
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    }

    static func fetchData() {
        do {
            addCategory = try context.fetch(Category.fetchRequest())
        }
        catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class CategoriesVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var collCategory: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collCategory.dataSource = self
        self.collCategory.delegate = self

        //categoryCoreData.fetchData()

    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        self.collCategory.reloadData()
    }

    //Collection View Data-Source Methods
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return addCategory.count + 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

        let cellID = indexPath.row < addCategory.count ? "CategoryCell" : "ExtraCell"

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)

        setupCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath, type: cellID)

        return cell
    }

    func setupCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath, type: String)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case "CategoryCell":
                setupCategoryCell(cell: cell as! CategoryCollectionCell, indexPath: indexPath)
            case "ExtraCell":
                setupAddButtonCell(cell: cell as! CategoryExtraCell, indexPath: indexPath)
            default:
                break
        }
    }

    func setupCategoryCell(cell: CategoryCollectionCell, indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            var countedValue: Int = 0

            for i in 0..<addCategory.count
            {
                let cat = addCategory[i]
                let strCatName = cat.category_name

                filterAllTask = CategoryTaskFilteredData.filterAllCategory(filteredObject: strCatName!)

                //All the tasks counted value and add in variable countedValue
                countedValue = filterAllTask.count + countedValue
            }

            //Counted value of all tasks
            cell.lblSubHeader.text = String(format: "%d Task Added", countedValue)
            cell.lblHeader.text = "All"
        }
        else
        {
            let cat = addCategory[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblHeader.text = cat.category_name

            filterCategoryTask = CategoryTaskFilteredData.filterCategory(filteredObject: cat.category_name!)
            cell.lblSubHeader.text = String(format: "%d Task Added", filterCategoryTask.count)
        }

    }

    func setupAddButtonCell(cell: CategoryExtraCell, indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        //Extra Button "Add Button" in a cell
    }

    //Set the CollectionViewCell size same for all iOS Devices
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = collectionView.bounds.width
        let height = collectionView.bounds.height
        return CGSize(width: (width / 2 - 1),height: height / 3)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.collCategory.allowsMultipleSelection = false

        if indexPath.row < addCategory.count
        {
            print("Main Cell")
            let categoryTaskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryTaskVC") as! CategoryTaskVC

            let cat = addCategory[indexPath.row]
            categoryTaskVC.strHeader = cat.category_name!



            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                print("entered 0")
                categoryTaskVC.selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
            }
            else
            {
                for i in 1..<addCategory.count
                {
                    if indexPath.row == i
                    {
                        print("entered \(i)")
                        categoryTaskVC.selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
                    }
                    else {
                        print("error")
                    }
                }
            }
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryTaskVC, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Add New Cell")

            self.blurEffects()
            view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

            //Alert View Controller when Adding Categories...
            let inputBox = BMInputBox.boxWithStyle(.plainTextInput)
            inputBox.blurEffectStyle = .extraLight

            inputBox.title = NSLocalizedString("Add Category", comment: "")
            inputBox.message = NSLocalizedString("Please enter unique category name.", comment: "")

            inputBox.customiseInputElement = {(element: UITextField) in

                element.placeholder = "Enter a category"
                return element
            }

            inputBox.submitButtonText = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "")

            inputBox.onSubmit = {(value: String...) in

                //Store value in text field in "text" object.
                for text in value
                {

                    let strCategory = text

                    print("STR CATE : \(strCategory)")



                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        //Store category in CoreData
                        categoryCoreData.saveData(tfCat: strCategory)

                        //Fetch Category Data
                        categoryCoreData.fetchData()
                        self.collCategory.reloadData()
                    })
                }
                self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()

            }


            inputBox.cancelButtonText = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "")

            inputBox.onCancel = {
                //Remove blur effects from Superview
                self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()

            }
            inputBox.show()
        }

    }


    @IBAction func btnAddTask(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let addTaskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddTaskVC") as! AddTaskVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addTaskVC, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post what actually error display in console ?

Comment: xcode quit and reopens automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is not your answer, but you can find where is your app crashed actually.

Add Exception break point by click on plus button and run your app again.

[image]

Comment: my app is crashed when i save in coredata and when i fetch from coredata.

Comment: @ARTunes, Have you fixed issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the case but sometimes autogenerated files with core data get messed up. Ensure you have cleaned your project product->clean. Then clean build folder product->"clean build folder" (you need to hold "alt" after pressing "product"). Then delete derived data Xcode->preferences->Locations, then press the right arrow below "Derived data", enter the "derived data" folder and delete the one that is named similar to your application (the folder will pop back up instantly but don't worry). Now try rebuilding.

Also make sure you have no warnings. This issue seems like something that may be produced when you have forgotten to assign some data types in your core data model.

After you have done both of this and the issue still persists I suggest you update your question with this information.